# How to find XML documents with certain attributes and nested elements?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I am searching for the regular expression that can find rows in an Oracle database. The rows contain a string that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<characteristics>
  <characteristic id="1001" mandatory="true" seq="1">
    <wildcard/>
  </characteristic>
  <characteristic id="10001" mandatory="false" seq="1">
    <value negation="false" seq="1">63</value>
  </characteristic>
  <characteristic id="10002" mandatory="false" seq="1">
    <value negation="false" seq="1">64</value>
  </characteristic>
  <characteristic id="10051" mandatory="false" seq="1">
    <value negation="false" seq="1">65</value>
  </characteristic>
  <characteristic id="10052" mandatory="false" seq="1">
    <value negation="false" seq="1">66</value>
  </characteristic>
  <characteristic id="1010" mandatory="false" seq="100">
    <wildcard/>
    <value negation="false" seq="1">314</value>
  </characteristic>
</characteristics>
```

The regular expression has to find all rows, that contain characteristics with special ids that contain a wildcard:

```
<wildcard/>
```

For Example: I want to get all rows, that contain the characteristics with ids 1000 and 1001 with wildcard. That means there must be the two strings

```
<characteristic id="1001" ...
  <wildcard/>
  ...
</characteristic>
```

and

```
<characteristic id="1000" ...
  <wildcard/>
  ...
</characteristic>
```

in it. Thereby the two strings can be in different orders.

Comment: Oracle has functions to deal with XML. There is no reason to do this with regular expressions. (Using regular expressions on XML is bad and wrong and you should always avoid it.)

Comment: I did not know that. How could I deal with this problem?

Comment: First research about how to handle XML in Oracle. [Here are a few examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+xml+xpath?sort=votes&pageSize=15) on StackOverflow to get you started, but looking into the documentation is also recommended.

Comment: `... WHERE existsnode(xmltype(column_name), '/characteristics/characteristic[@id="1000"]/wildcard') = 1`

Comment: Good start! does it work?

Comment: this works, although it is not extremely fast, but i assume there is no fast way... Thanks

Comment: Change the column data type to XML so you don't have to do type conversion in your query. Also, *"I have this SQL/XML query in Oracle, my table has these basic characteristics (row count, data types), my query works, but why is it so slow?"* is a good question you can ask separately.

Comment: @Garrarufa, please put your comment as an answer (You can copy my post and then I'll delete it). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is stored as XMLtype

```
select *
from   t
where  EXISTSNODE(doc,'/characteristics/characteristic[@id="1000"]/wildcard') = 1
  and  EXISTSNODE(doc,'/characteristics/characteristic[@id="1001"]/wildcard') = 1
;
```

Alternative syntax (as suggested by @Tomalak)

```
select *
from   t
where  EXISTSNODE(doc,'/characteristics[characteristic[@id="1001"]/wildcard and characteristic[@id="1010"]/wildcard]') = 1
```

For learning purposes, in case the data is stored as string

```
select *
from   (select xmltype(doc) as doc from t)
where  EXISTSNODE(doc,'/characteristics/characteristic[@id="1000"]/wildcard') = 1
  and  EXISTSNODE(doc,'/characteristics/characteristic[@id="1001"]/wildcard') = 1
;
```

Comment: If you put less whitespace after the SQL keywords, the horizontal scrollbar isn't needed, making for easier reading.

Comment: @SQB, I'm using laptop and see no scroll bar.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm using a desktop with monitors that should be big enough, but I still get scrollbars. Weird. I hope you don't mind me editing it.

Comment: @SQB the OCD is kicking in :-))

Comment: @SQB, in any case I'm waiting for Garrarufa to convert is commecnt to an answer and then I'll delete this one

Comment: It's potentially faster to check both conditions in one XPath expression. `EXISTSNODE(doc,'/characteristics[characteristic[@id="1000"]/wildcard and characteristic[@id="1001"]/wildcard]')`.

Comment: ... = 1, of course. I was focusing on the XPath. :)

Comment: @Tomalak, I see no improvement in performance for xmltype column - I don't think there is an optimization for paths with a common prefix. In any case, I've added your suggestion as an alternative solution. Thanks :-)

Comment: I have no way to test, so thanks for trying it out. :)